# Extracting variable names from llvm IR

Tags: llvm

I am referring `findDbgDeclare` function of [this](https://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/llvm/branches/GSoC/adaptive-compilation/lib/Analysis/DbgInfoPrinter.cpp) to find variable names corresponding to `Value` objects occurring as operands of an instruction. Like this:

```
for (User::op_iterator opnd = iCmpInst->op_begin(), oe = iCmpInst->op_end(); opnd != oe; opnd ++)
{
  const Value* V = opnd->get();         
  errs() << findDbgDeclare(V).str() << "\n";
}
```

where iCmpInst is an `icmp` instruction.

However, this statement does not seem to work: `if (DDI->getAddress() == V)`

Can someone please explain why?

Comment: Please be more specific than "does not seem to work".

Comment: @Ismail Badawi: The condition is false. That is, DDI->getAddress() returns different address than the address of V.

Comment: However, when I print the variable name like this: `errs() << DDI->getVariable()->getName().str();` inside `findDbgDeclare` function, all the local variables get printed.